# Why doesn't the event listener gets removed immediately after the function gets executed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm expecting is when I click on **button 4** the event listener should **immediately** gets removed from **button 1**, but what actually happens is that the **event listener** stops only after clicking **button 1** one time.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.container').children;

for (let x = 0; x < btn.length; x++) {

  btn[x].addEventListener('click', changeFontSize);

  function changeFontSize() {
    // changing the font sizes from 16 to 20 , or the opposite.
    if (getComputedStyle(btn[x]).fontSize == '16px') {
      btn[x].style.fontSize = '20px';
    } else {
      btn[x].style.fontSize = '16px';
    }

    // nesting a function to remove the event listener form btn0 after btn4 gets clicked on
    if (getComputedStyle(btn[3]).fontSize == '20px') {
      btn[0].removeEventListener('click', changeFontSize);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id='btn'>btn 1</button>
  <button id='btn'>btn 2</button>
  <button id='btn'>btn 3</button>
  <button id='btn'>btn 4</button>
  <button id='btn'>btn 1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When button 4's event listener removal is executed, it's trying to remove its own reference to `function changeFontSize()` in its closure from button 1. This operation fails because button 1 doesn't have button 4's handler attached to it. After clicking button 4, it may be in a state where its `fontSize == "20px"` is true. The next time you click button 1 with button 4 in this state, button 1 successfully removes its own listener, but only after changing its font size one final time.

Furthermore, when clicked, the `if` in all other buttons try futilely to remove their listener from button 0 when button 4 is in its `fontSize == "20px"` state.

Minimal repro of the problem:

```js
const [foo, bar] = document.querySelectorAll("button");
let barClicked = false;

function fooClickHandler () {
  console.log("foo clicked");
  
  if (barClicked) {
    foo.removeEventListener("click", fooClickHandler);
    console.log("foo listener removed");
  }
}

function barClickHandler () {
  console.log("bar clicked");
  barClicked = true;
  foo.removeEventListener("click", barClickHandler); // does nothing
}

foo.addEventListener("click", fooClickHandler);
bar.addEventListener("click", barClickHandler);
```

```html
<button>foo</button>
<button>bar</button>
```

You could store the event handler callback function in a variable specifically for button 1 and make sure button 4's handler removes exactly button 1's handler function. But the overall design seems quite brittle as-is so I'd recommend a re-think, depending on what your app context is.

Offhand, I'm not sure if 1em in the CSS will guarantee your initial 16px size. I'd set it explicitly to 16px in the CSS if that's what you expect it to be. Hardcoding these sizes into the JS is a bit of a code smell.

Ids must be unique in the whole DOM, which is not the case here.

As an aside, always use `===` instead of `==` and `const`/`let` instead of `var` in general, although that's not the bug here.

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you mean by << This operation fails because button 1 doesn't have button 4's handler attached to it >> .. If could elaborate more please.

Comment: I tried the solution you came up with and it seems that it works pretty much good. But as you said the overall design looks messed up. anyways appreciate your help <3

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better approach...

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".container").children;

for (let x = 0; x < btn.length; x++) {
  btn[x].addEventListener("click", changeFontSize);

  function changeFontSize() {
    btn[x].classList.toggle("fontsize");

    for (let y = 0; y < btn.length; y++) {
      if (y !== x) {
        btn[y].classList.remove("fontsize");
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.fontsize {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">btn 1</button>
  <button class="btn">btn 2</button>
  <button class="btn">btn 3</button>
  <button class="btn">btn 4</button>
  <button class="btn">btn 1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a better approach? It doesn't answer OP's question and doesn't match their specification, either (button 4 is supposed to instantly disable button 1). Beyond that, it repeats the illegal HTML with the same id on multiple elements.

Comment: @ggorlen I have changed ids to classes, by the explanation I thought he is asking for an effect like this.